# Detect incorrect makernote offsets in metadata-extractor

Tags: metadata-extractor

EXIFTool can detect when the offset of tags is incorrect

*[ExifTool]      Warning                         : [minor] Possibly incorrect maker notes offsets (fix by 1060?)*

see [FAQ](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q15). Can we detect incorrect offsets with metadata-extractor and ideally fix them in the same way?

Comment: Could you please file this feature request against the library directly and include a sample image that reproduces the problem? Even better, file a PR :) https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Comment: @DrewNoakes so I assume the answer to my question is no.

Comment: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/404

Answer (score 1):

From https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q15:

> 1) Use the -F option to allow ExifTool to attempt to fix the incorrect
>   offsets. If ExifTool was correct in its diagnosis, then this option
>   will fix the incorrect offsets. This is usually the appropriate choice
>   if this problem was caused by editing the image with other software.